# List box is not resizing to fit longest item

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms

I am using a windows forms list box that is placed inside of a table layout panel having column set to autosize.

When the list box is getting an item with a long name the list box is not rezising to display the entire content of the item and displaies it cutted, like for instance in the picture below:

[image]

Do you know a way to make the list box to resize automatically to fit the size of the longest item from its content ?

Comment: You'd have to take care of that yourself, not so easy to do 100% correctly since you don't know the margins it uses.  DPI awareness is the trap.  Consider instead a ListView with View = List and ShowItemsToolTips = True.

Comment: Have a look at the given answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use:

```
listBox1.HorizontalScrollbar = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

`PreferredHeight` sets your listbox height to your combined items length.

When adding an item `SizeChanged` will get called as you will be changing your listbox size. What happens next is simple:
1) We use [`MeasureString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring(v=vs.110).aspx) to measure the last added item onto `listBox` width, which is using the `Arial` font and `12p`as the size. If the result is bigger than your listBox width, the width will be updated.

```
listBox1.SizeChanged += (_sender, args) =>
{
    listBox1.Height = listBox1.PreferredHeight;
    var CurrentItemWidth = (int)this.CreateGraphics().MeasureString(listBox1.Items[listBox1.Items.Count - 1].ToString(), listBox1.Font, TextRenderer.MeasureText(listBox1.Items[listBox1.Items.Count - 1].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 12.0F))).Width;
    if(CurrentItemWidth > listBox1.Width)
        listBox1.Width = CurrentItemWidth;
};

listBox1.Items.Add("asd");
listBox1.Items.Add("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
```

Comment: Thank's for your suggestion, i tried it but it did not worked. I initialized the size changed event handler of the list box after the InitializeComponent() call but the list items were still cutted. Did you try the sample, how is it working for you ?

Comment: Yes, it is working. I've tested it. You need to set the font and font size of the Lisbox to match the MeasureString arguments.

Comment: Ok... i set the font of my list box to "Arial" and then the font size to "12" since "12.0F" i could not enter from the designer and the items were still cut.

Comment: Post a screenshot please

Comment: There you go... I added them as a separate answer since i could not add pictures to a comment. I added the font settings of the list view, where i added your code and the content of the list box items.

Comment: You should add your items after the code is in place. Try to add two after my code. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the captures required from Zroq's comment

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Code is already posted in the below anwser. I just wanted to show quicker to Zroq where I added his code.